# Android place image views perfectly for all devices

Tags: android

I want to make UI for my app.
Think of a black background image with a button on it called "water".
The button is on a specific place on the background.
I splitted the background to 2 images: the background, and the button.

In my RelativeLayout I want to place the button on the background,
but on the exact place of the background.
So I set the background in android:background for my RealtiveLayout,
and create an ImageView for the button.

How can I keep the button in the correct place on the background?
How game developers do that in their games?
I have to use the DP? PIXELS? How I can do that?

In addition, I tried to set X and Y point for the "water" ImageView, 
but it is allowed for API 11 and up (I use API 8).
How can I set X and Y point in code?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an drawn image of what you want to achieve

Comment: This is what i want : http://srv2.jpg.co.il/7/55e1fc1249675.png

Comment: The "water" button on the background.